# Persistent selectList causing error of "Couldn't match type ‘BaseBackend backend0’ with ‘SqlBackend’"

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I'm running into the below compile error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘BaseBackend backend0’ with ‘SqlBackend’
    arising from a use of ‘runSqlite’
  The type variable ‘backend0’ is ambiguous
• In the expression: runSqlite ":memory:"
  In the expression:
    runSqlite ":memory:"
    $ do { records <- selectList [UserUsername ==. "abc"] [LimitTo 10];
           liftIO $ print (records :: [Entity User]) }
  In an equation for ‘selectAll’:
      selectAll
        = runSqlite ":memory:"
          $ do { records <- selectList [UserUsername ==. "abc"] [LimitTo 10];
                 liftIO $ print (records :: [Entity User]) }
```

Code:

```
selectAll :: IO ()
selectAll = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
  records <- selectList [UserUsername ==. "abc"] [LimitTo 10]
  liftIO $ print (records :: [Entity User])
```

Having a look at the type signature of runSqlite:

```
runSqlite    
:: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m, IsSqlBackend backend)  
=> Text 
-> ReaderT backend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) a 
-> m a
```

I would assume I need to specify an explicit type for runSqlite, though I'm not too sure what I set for `backend` in `ReaderT backend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) a`?

Comment: That should work, can you post the entire code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specialize it at `SqlBackend`.

```
asSqlBackendReader :: ReaderT SqlBackend m a -> ReaderT SqlBackend m a
asSqlBackendReader = id

selectAll :: IO ()
selectAll = runSqlite ":memory:" . asSqlBackendReader $ do
  records <- selectList [UserUsername ==. "abc"] [LimitTo 10]
  liftIO $ print (records :: [Entity User])
```

---

Looking at the type of `runSqlite`, there is a `IsSqlBackend backend` constraint to satisfy.

The definition of [`IsSqlBackend`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.7.0/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#t:IsSqlBackend) is:

```
type IsSqlBackend backend =
  (IsPersistBackend backend, BaseBackend backend ~ SqlBackend)
```

Then look up [`IsPersistBackend`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.7.0/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#t:IsPersistBackend).

Just below the definition of the class, we see that it has three instances:

```
instance IsPersistBackend SqlWriteBackend
instance IsPersistBackend SqlReadBackend
instance IsPersistBackend SqlBackend
```

The three types specify backends with various capabilities, with `SqlBackend` being the most general one (unknown capabilities). Feel free to use a more restricted one if that's all you need.

Comment: Could you possibly suggest a resource to read up on to understand this answer?  Thank you!

Comment: I modified my answer to be more descriptive. I don't have any particular resource in mind explaining the process at a higher level.