# Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend (Entity a)’ with ‘SqlBackend’

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I've got the following:

```
asSqlBackendReader :: ReaderT SqlBackend m a -> ReaderT SqlBackend m a
asSqlBackendReader = id

insertEnt :: (Entity a) -> IO (Key (Entity a))
insertEnt x = runWithDb $ do
  insert $ x
  where runWithDb = runSqlite "test.db" . asSqlBackendReader
```

The purpose of the `asSqlBAckendReader` is due to [Persistent selectList causing error of "Couldn't match type ‘BaseBackend backend0’ with ‘SqlBackend’"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249710/persistent-selectlist-causing-error-of-couldnt-match-type-basebackend-backend).

I'm running into an error of:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend (Entity a)’
                 with ‘SqlBackend’
    arising from a use of ‘insert’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: insert $ x
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘do { insert $ x }’
  In the expression: runWithDb $ do { insert $ x }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the constraint to the signature of `insertEnt`. You'll also need a `PersistEntity` constraint.

```
insertEnt
  :: ( PersistEntity (Entity a)
     , PersistEntityBackend (Entity a) ~ SqlBackend)
  => Entity a -> IO (Key (Entity a))
```

---

To deduce that (other than just giving the compiler what it's indirectly asking), you may look at [the type of `insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.7.0/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:insert)

```
insert
  :: ( PersistStoreWrite backend
     , MonadIO m
     , PersistRecordBackend record backend)
  => record -> ReaderT backend m (Key record)
```

We also have

```
type PersistRecordBackend record backend =
  ( PersistEntity record
  , PersistEntityBackend record ~ BaseBackend backend)
```

Furthermore, in your application you have some concrete types:

```
backend ~ SqlBackend
m ~ (some concrete transformer stack on top of IO)
record ~ Entity a
```

These concrete types discharge `PersistStoreWrite backend` and `MonadIO m`, and since `Entity a` is still mostly abstract, you are left with the two constraints that define `PersistRecordBackend`. You could in fact use that synonym as a shorthand:

```
insertEnt
  :: PersistRecordBackend (Entity a) SqlBackend
  => Entity a -> IO (Key (Entity a))
```