# Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend U’ with ‘SqlBackend’

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

The following code produces a compile error `Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend U’ with ‘SqlBackend’ arising from a use of ‘insertUser’` due to the commented line:

```
sampleUser :: Entity User
sampleUser = Entity (toSqlKey 1) $ User
  { userName = "admin"
  , userEmail = "admin@test.com"
  }

type U = Entity User

connectInfo :: MySQLConnectInfo
connectInfo = undefined

runAction :: (MonadUnliftIO m, IsPersistBackend r, BaseBackend r ~ SqlBackend) => MySQLConnectInfo -> ReaderT r (LoggingT m) a -> m a
runAction connectInfo action = runStdoutLoggingT $ withMySQLConn connectInfo $ \backend ->
  runReaderT action backend

insertUser :: (PersistEntity U, PersistRecordBackend U SqlBackend) => 
             U -> ReaderT SqlBackend (LoggingT IO) (Key U) 
insertUser = insert

doDBStuff :: IO ()
doDBStuff = do
  runAction connectInfo (runMigration migrateAll)
  runAction connectInfo (insertUser sampleUser) -- compile error
  return ()
```

As far as I can see, I've specialized all the types in `insertUser` and have added all necessary constraints (having read the [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272380/couldnt-match-type-persistentitybackend-entity-a-with-sqlbackend)). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `PersistRecordBackend U SqlBackend` constraint I don't know if you need, but I suspect you need a `PersistEntityBackend U ~ SqlBackend` constraint for `insertUser`. Or so the compiler suggests.

See [Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend (Entity a)’ with ‘SqlBackend’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272380/couldnt-match-type-persistentitybackend-entity-a-with-sqlbackend)

Comment: The error remains; I was under the impression that `PersistEntityBackend U ~ SqlBackend` was already covered by the `PersistRecordBackend U SqlBackend` constraint alias.

Comment: You're absolutely right, as can be seen in in an appendix in an answer to the very Q&A we both linked. I should've read further before dismissing this as a duplicate question. It follows that your PersistEntity U constraint on the type of insertUser is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Asking ghci `:info User` gave me the right hint: It shows its class instances. It turns out that it is wrong to use `Entity User` directly. I suspect that while this creates the entity, all the class instances generated by `Database.Persist.TH.share` are missing from it. Following code compiles, having also removed the redundant constraint as mentioned by Bjartur:

```
sampleUser :: User
sampleUser = User
  { userName = "admin"
  , userEmail = "admin@test.com"
  }

type U = User

connectInfo :: MySQLConnectInfo
connectInfo = undefined

runAction :: (MonadUnliftIO m, IsPersistBackend r, BaseBackend r ~ SqlBackend) => MySQLConnectInfo -> ReaderT r (LoggingT m) a -> m a
runAction connectInfo action = runStdoutLoggingT $ withMySQLConn connectInfo $ \backend ->
  runReaderT action backend

insertUser :: (PersistRecordBackend U SqlBackend) => 
             U -> ReaderT SqlBackend (LoggingT IO) (Key U) 
insertUser = insert

doDBStuff :: IO ()
doDBStuff = do
  runAction connectInfo (runMigration migrateAll)
  runAction connectInfo (insertUser sampleUser) -- compile error fixed
  return ()
```

Comment: Well done! I agree with you that the error stemmed from there being no PersistEntity instance for U.